# Drawing a pair from a poker hand, unordered with replacement

Tags: combinatorics

I am wondering in how many ways you can draw a pair from a poker hand, if order does not matter in the context of cards in the hand, and if the cards can be replaced with every draw?

I know that you can draw a pair from a poker hand, unordered without replacement in 
13*(4 choose 2)*(12 choose 3)*4^3 ways/(52 choose 5) = 1098240/2598960, where 13 = number of ways to specify the denomination for the pair, (4 choose 2) = # of ways to specify the two cards from the denomination, (12 choose 3) = # of ways of specifying the other three denominations, and 4^3 = # of ways of specifying the other three cards from those denominations.

Also, I know that the formula for unordered with replacement is (n+k-1 choose k), however I don't know how to put everything together.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking the following question. Draw a card from the deck, record what it was, replace it in the deck. Do this a total of $5$ times.

How many records are there, where *order does not matter*, and the record qualifies as a $1$-pair hand.

In this setup, it is possible that the "hand" will consist of $\heartsuit$ Q, $\heartsuit$ Q, and three useless cards. Should this count as a $1$-pair hand? In a real poker game, it would probably get the other players upset. But we will allow it.

The *kind* that we have a pair of can be chosen in $\binom{13}{2}$ ways. The actual cards in the pair can then be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}+4$ ways.

As to the rest of the cards, we need to choose $3$ kinds from the remaining $12$, and for each kind choose a card. There are $\binom{12}{3}\binom{4}{1}^3$ ways to do this.

Now we have all the ingredients. It is really pretty much the same as the conventional $1$-pair problem. The only difference is that we have $\binom{4}{2}+4$ where the $1$-pair answer has $\binom{4}{2}$.

Comment: Nicolas Great explanation. Just one question - Why can the actual cards in the pair be chosen in (4 2) + 4 ways?

Comment: There are fancy ways of doing this sort of problem, not needed since numbers are small. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ wats to choose $2$ **different** cards from the $4$ say Kings. To this add the $4$ "pairs" consisting of two copies of say the same King.

Comment: Ok, so is the answer then (13 choose 2)*(12 choose 3)*(4 choose 1)^3 * ((4 choose 2) + 4)/(52^5)?

Comment: No, no, no! You asked for the number of different **hands**, and I answered that. You did not ask for a probability. The various hands are not all equally likely. And your denominator of $52^5$ counts order, while the number of hands is insensitive to order. The probability calculation would be very different. If you wish, you can ask for the probability, it is a very different question,

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I meant to ask for the probability!!